# Влияет ли размер css файла на загрузку страницы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

К примеру у меня в css файле написано более 1к строк или к примеру файл весит более 1 мб... Может ли это повлиять на загрузку страницы?

Если к примеру для каждой страницы(к примеру) писать отдельный css файл, получается страница будет быстрее загружаться?

Comment: Да, каждый файл влияет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вес всего, что вы размещаете на странице будет влиять на её загрузку. Однако, есть и вторая сторона вопроса. Разбив файл на множество мелких, подгружая их в каждом нужном разделе, вы увеличиваете количество запросов, необходимых для чтения этих файлов.

Что же делать, в такой ситуации?

1) Используйте сжатие. Пример, [тут](https://csscompressor.com/).

2) Уменьшайте количество стилей путем переноса в нужные страницы, но, только там, где страницы не индексируются или находится единичный элемент.

Пример:

- Код формы или страницы регистрации можно вынести в отдельный файл. В общем-то, для всех служебных участков, которые закрыты от индексации можно писать отдельные стили.
- Если основной слайдер на главной странице более нигде не размещается, тогда вынесите его стили в inline.

Если говорить обобщенно, в основной таблице оставляйте только те стили, которые участвуют на всех видимых страницах по несколько раз.

3) Некоторым стилям задавайте отдельные классы и используйте их при работе с HTML.

Например:

Запишите `transition: all .5s;` таким образом:

```
.transition {
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;
 -o-transition: all .5s;
 transition: all .5s;
}
```

Затем подставляйте этот класс непосредственно при работе с кодом страницы.

```
<div class="element transition">...</div>
```

Таким образом вы существенно уменьшите количество повторов для таких стилей как `user-select`, элементов Flexbox и других.

Все эти советы применимы и к файлам JS.

Обобщенно говоря, ваша задача максимально уменьшить размер всего, что загружается на странице, не только файлов, но и их количества.

Если кто-то что-то добавит, будет вообще супер!

Answer (score 2):

Конечно влияет. Но только при первом обращении, далее любой нормальный браузер просто закеширует его. Если хотите чтобы уж очень быстро, используйте inline стили, но это сами понимаете не очень красиво и тем более не очень удобно и практично. Хотя я использовал такой подход при работе с Vue.js например для разработки админ панели. Если для вас важно СЕО, думаю это не очень хорошая идея. Насчет разбить на страницы, можно с точки зрения удобства разработки, но не забывайте что это повлечет за собой и увелечение кол-ва запросов к серверу.
Хотя если вы используете какой нибудь Webpack то это не проблема насколько я знаю.

Comment: Сам по себе браузер не станет ничего кэшировать. Не вводите в заблуждение.

Comment: Я никого никуда не ввожу, если для вас это стало открытием, рад за Вас.

Comment: @netseac все же Yami прав. Для того, чтоб файл какой-то кешировался, необходимо оставить команду со стороны сервера. Только это не по теме вопроса.

Comment: @Alexey Giryayev,  _оставить команду со стороны сервера_ возможно это зависит от браузера/сервера, в опере именно в заголовках запроса запрашивается кеширование, понятное дело что сервер должен его поддерживать.

Answer (score 1):

> Может ли это повлиять на загрузку страницы?

Логически да, практически (и да и нет).

1. Сжатие.

   - Если у вас в `css` комментарии, пробелы, переносы строк, то первое о
     чем вам стоит задуматься, это об оптимизации `css`, а точнее о его
     сжатии, максимальном. Т.е. когда вы откроете файл, там все будет в 1
     строку, без лишних пробелов и т.д и т.п.
2. Кэширование статических файлов.

   - Как мы знаем, браузеры умеют хранить кэш веб-страниц. Вот тут то там и поможет как минимум ускорить загрузку страниц, так это кэширование файлов которые часто используются, но не часто изменяются, или совсем никогда.

Comment: Я бы ещё про скорость DNS-серверов пунктик добавил... Особенно если это все не на одном сервере лежит. Часто можно увидеть сайт, в котором маленькие файлы, но их много, и грузится это супердолго

Comment: @selya: ТС интересуется видимо исключительно css файлом : ) А так да, согласен.